# What is the difference between switch and select in Go?

Tags: go, switch-statement, goroutine

Is there any difference between `switch` and `select` in Go,
apart from the fact that one takes an argument and the other not?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A `select` is only used with channels. [Example](https://gobyexample.com/select)

A `switch` is used with concrete types. [Example](https://gobyexample.com/switch)

A `select` will choose multiple valid options at random, while a`switch` will go in sequence (and would require a fallthrough to match multiple.)

Note that a switch can also go over types for interfaces when used with the keyword `.(type)`

```golang
var a interface{}
a = 5
switch a.(type) {
case int:
     fmt.Println("an int.")
case int32:
     fmt.Println("an int32.")
}
// in this case it will print "an int."
```

Comment: Would be good if you expanded on the `switch` explanation. It's not simply restricted to concrete types. By default, it does an equality check, and with no argument, each case statement must be a boolean expression, with the first `true` case being chosen.

Answer (score 44):

**switch** is used to make a decision based on a variable value of any type. Read [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch) for more details:

> Go's switch is more general than C's. The expressions need not be constants or even integers, the cases are evaluated top to bottom until a match is found, and if the switch has no expression it switches on true. It's therefore possible—and idiomatic—to write an if-else-if-else chain as a switch.

Sample Use: ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g7F7d7OG43))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Go runs on ")
    switch os := runtime.GOOS; os {
    case "darwin":
        fmt.Println("OS X.")
    case "linux":
        fmt.Println("Linux.")
    default:
        // freebsd, openbsd,
        // plan9, windows...
        fmt.Printf("%s.", os)
    }
}
```

The **select** statement lets a goroutine wait on multiple communication operations.

A select blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case. It chooses one at random if multiple are ready. Here is one example: ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ipOXPcmWcL))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Println("tick.")
        case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is a funny joke  ⏰

Answer (score 9):

[Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

> A "select" statement chooses which of a set of possible send or
>   receive operations will proceed. It looks similar to a "switch"
>   statement but with the cases all referring to communication
>   operations.

[Switch statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)

> "Switch" statements provide multi-way execution. An expression or type
>   specifier is compared to the "cases" inside the "switch" to determine
>   which branch to execute. There are two forms: expression switches and
>   type switches. In an expression switch, the cases contain expressions
>   that are compared against the value of the switch expression. In a
>   type switch, the cases contain types that are compared against the
>   type of a specially annotated switch expression. The switch expression
>   is evaluated exactly once in a switch statement.

Yes, there are many differences:

- `select` works just on channel events (receive, close or wait), but you can use `switch` just for comparing channel data like `case <-ch == 1:`
- `switch` works in deterministic way like multiple `if` or `if else` statement, but `select` chooses the `case` in non-deterministic way: you can't say which case runs first in `select`
- you can't use `fallthrough` in `select`
- in `switch` An expression or type specifier is compared to the `cases` inside the `switch` to determine which branch to execute.
- `switch` is not blocking itself, but `select` is blocking underlying goroutine unless you use `default`
- `switch` has two forms: expression switches and type switches
- in blocking `select` (without `default`) there is no CPU usage (goroutine sleep)
- Unlike `select` you can't use `case <-ch:` inside `switch`.

Working sample Code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 4)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    close(ch)
    switch {
    //case <-ch: //  invalid case <-ch in switch (mismatched types int and bool)
    case <-ch == 1:
        fmt.Println("switch1")
        fallthrough
    case <-ch == 2:
        fmt.Println("switch2")
    }
    select {
    case d := <-ch:
        fmt.Println("select1 d=", d)
    case d := <-ch:
        fmt.Println("select2 d=", d)
    }
}
```

output:

```
switch1
switch2
select2 d= 2
```

output of another run:

```
switch1
switch2
select1 d= 2
```